# Adding rows of values to a dataframe in new columns, based on values in existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Columns that I already have saved as a dataframe: 'date', 'high', 'close,' 'target,' and 'portion'

I am trying to create columns 'capital,' 'trade,' 'quantity,'  and 'gain_loss' to the existing dataframe by performing operations row by row.

I'm trying to:

1. Start with a value of 1000 for capital.
2. Calculate trade by capital * portion.
3. Calculate quantity by trade / target price.
4. Calculate gain/loss by close * quantity - target * quantity
5. Calculate capital of next row = capital + gain/loss
6. Repeat for next row.

Something I'm struggling with is:
I only want gain/loss to be added to the capital of next row if high > target

For example, on the first row, high > target, which means the gain/loss on the first row should be added to the next row capital.

However, on the second row, high < target, which means whatever the gain/loss is on the second row should NOT be added to the next row capital. Instead, I want the second row capital to be simply carried over to the third row.

Below is what I want it to look like:

| date | high | close | target | portion | capital | trade | quantity | gain/loss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 110 | 150 | 100 | 0.2 | 1000 | 1000*0.2 | (1000*0.2) / 100 | 0 |
| 1 | 250 | 200 | 260 | 0.6 | 1000 | 1100*0.6 | (1100*0.6) / 260 | 0 (since high < target, no trade executed) |
| 2 | 350 | 320 | 280 | 0.5 | 1000 | 1000 * 0.5 | (1000*0.5) / 280 | 71.2 |
| 3 | 410 | 500 | 500 | 0.3 | 1071.2 |  |  |  |

Here is what I've tried. My if-statement isn't operating as I intended. I'm also getting "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

```
df.at[0, 'capital'] = 10000
df.at[0, 'gain_loss'] = 0
for i in range(1, 500):
    if df['high'] < df['target']:
        df.at[i, 'capital'] = df.at[i - 1, 'capital']
        df.at[i, 'trade_amount'] = df.at[i, 'capital'] * df.at[i, 'portion']
        df.at[i, 'quantity'] = df.at[i, 'trade_amount'] / df.at[i, 'target']
        df.at[i, 'gain_loss'] = 0
    else:
        df.at[i, 'capital'] = df.at[i - 1, 'capital'] + df.at[i - 1, 'gain_loss']
        df.at[i, 'trade_amount'] = df.at[i, 'capital'] * df.at[i, 'portion']
        df.at[i, 'quantity'] = df.at[i, 'trade_amount'] / df.at[i, 'target']
        df.at[i, 'gain_loss'] = (df.at[i, 'close'] - df.at[i, 'target']) * df.at[i, 'quantity']
```

*EDIT

```
df.at[0, 'capital'] = 1000
df.at[0, 'gain_loss'] = 0

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['high'] > row['target']:
        df.at[i, 'trade_amount'] = df.at[i, 'capital'] * row['portion']
        df.at[i, 'quantity'] = df.at[i, 'trade_amount'] / row['target']
        df.at[i, 'gain_loss'] = (row['close'] - row['target']) * df.at[i, 'quantity']
        df.at[i + 1, 'capital'] = df.at[i, 'capital'] + df.at[i, 'gain_loss']
    else:
        df.at[i, 'trade_amount'] = df.at[i, 'capital'] * row['portion']
        df.at[i, 'quantity'] = df.at[i, 'trade_amount'] / row['target']
        df.at[i, 'gain_loss'] = 0
        df.at[i + 1, 'capital'] = df.at[i, 'capital']
```

Comment: kindly add your expected output dataframe

Comment: Please add a df with values in the calculated fields, for example, in your code, the first row has 'capital' = 10000 and 'gain_loss' = 0. But in your table 'gain_loss' in the first row has a value of 100.

Comment: Right, that was a typo. Thanks for catching that. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by adding a df. Is the table that I posted insufficient?

Comment: Why in row with date=1 has a value of 1100 in capital column? If the gain in the previous row is zero.  In your edited code that adds a new row at the end, Is that what you expected?

Comment: That is a good point. I've fixed it to what it should look like. I also just noticed that there was an extra row at the end like you pointed out. If I didn't want that last row, would I just have to use df.drop to drop the last row?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see there is a problem with the conditional "if". In that line, you are comparing the whole column, not just the rows' values.

On the other hand, maybe you need to set some initial conditions in first row. And add some controls to your loop.

```py
data = {'date': [0, 1, 2, 3], 
        'high': [110, 250, 350, 410], 
        'close': [150, 200, 320, 500], 
        'target': [100, 260, 280, 500], 
        'portion': [0.2, 0.6, 0.5, 0.3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```py
df.at[0, 'capital'] = 1000

nrow = df.shape[0]
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['high'] < row['target']:
        df.at[i, 'gain_loss'] = 0
    else:
        df.at[i, 'trade_amount'] = df.at[i, 'capital'] * df.at[i,'portion']
        df.at[i, 'quantity'] = df.at[i, 'trade_amount'] / df.at[i,'target']
        df.at[i, 'gain_loss'] = (df.at[i, 'close'] - df.at[i, 'target']) * df.at[i, 'quantity']
    if i < nrow-1:
        df.at[i+1, 'capital'] = df.at[i, 'capital'] + df.at[i, 'gain_loss']
        
display(df)
```

[image]

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Any idea why 'gain_loss' is not adding to capital on your output?

Comment: It adds 'gain_loss'. According to your description 'gain_loss' is zero in first row and rows where 'high' < 'target', only has a different value in cases where 'high' >= 'target' (Index = 2) in your sample data.  If you need to add that to 'capital' then you have to do that after 'gain_loss' is calculated.  Value of 'gain_loss' is added to 'capital' only with two consecutive rows get inside your else.

Comment: Would you mind checking the modification that I made on my post? Just wondering if this is how you would go about solving the problem if I wanted capital added after gain_loss is calculated. df output looks like it's doing what I intended to do. I've exported df output to excel b/c there were too many columns in df. Any suggestion is appreciated!